# alasql: application performance is not affected when saving all data in an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, alasql

I'm developing an electronjs application

I have a table that has 35 fields and users will record an approximate between 5000 and 40000 records in that table per month. I did some storage tests with FILESTORAGE of alasql and saved the objects of the database file in an object

My question is, would not it affect the performance of my application having so much persistent data in an object?
If so, what do you recommend me to do?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I realized that the best way to store large amounts of data on a computer locally would be with sqlite3 or using a more powerful database server like SQLServer but if it will be too much data the most viable option is sqlite3 since it does not require installation by the user, you just have to compile the binaries and do the installer with electron-builder (it does everything for you). By the way if they take automatic updates keep in mind that the relative routes are a bad practice they have to save data with [app.getPath ('userData')](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#appgetpathname)